# I need to run a fair dice simulation multiple times

Tags: r, statistics, probability-distribution

I have a program that simulates a dice roll 100 times. I need to know how to run this program 10^5 times, I think it is something to do with numeric.

```
 set.seed(123)

 x <- sample(1:6, size=100, replace = TRUE)

 hist(x,
 main="10^6 fair rolls",
 xlab = "Dice Result",
 ylab = "Probability",
 xlim=c(0.5,6.5),
 breaks=-1:100+.5,
 prob=TRUE )
```

Comment: Do you need `?replicate` ?

Comment: @markus no, I do not

Comment: Why not `sample(1:6, size=100 * 10^5, replace = TRUE)` ? Wouldn't it be the same?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @markus, you can use `replicate`:

```
set.seed(123)

nTime <- 10^5

x <- replicate(nTime, sample(1:6, size=100, replace = TRUE))

hist(x,
     main="10^6 fair rolls",
     xlab = "Dice Result",
     ylab = "Probability",
     xlim=c(0.5,6.5),
     breaks=-1:100+.5,
     prob=TRUE )
```

[image]